# Limiting Distribution of $n\left[Y_n\right]$ where $Y_n$ is the minimum of a sample of size n from Uniform$\left(0,\theta\right)$ distribution

Tags: distributions, convergence, uniform-distribution, asymptotics, extreme-value

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ is a random sample from *Uniform*$(0,\theta)$ for some unknown $\theta > 0$. Let $Y_n$ be the minimum of $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$.

(a) Suppose $F_n$ is the CDF of $nY_n$. Show that for any real x, $F_n(x)$  converges to $F(x)$, where F is the CDF of an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$.

(b) Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(n[Y_n]=k)$ for $k = 0,1,2,\dots$, where $[x]$ denotes the largest integer less than or equal to x.

I have been able to solve part (a) but unable to solve part (b).Could someone help solve this question?

My attempt at solving part (b):

$P(n[Y_n]=k) = P([Y_n]=\frac{k}{n}) = P(\frac{k}{n}\leq Y_n<\frac{k}{n}+1) = (\frac{\theta-\frac{k}{n}}{\theta})^n-\{\frac{\theta-(\frac{k}{n}+1)}{\theta}\}^n$

The first terms tends to $e^\frac{-k}{\theta}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ but I am unable to find the limit of the second term.

It has not been mentioned whether part (a) has to be used to solve part (b) but it is very much likely that it should be the case.

Comment: Since $[Y_n]$ converges to $1,$ which makes (b) uninteresting, did you perhaps intend to write "$[nY_n]$" instead of "$n[Y_n]$"?

Comment: No the question is as stated and could you clarify why $[Y_n]$ converges to 1? I do notice that if the question involved $[nY_n]$ then the limiting distribution is a geometric distribution. However that is unfortunately not what the question states.

Comment: When the sample size is large, the minimum $Y_n$ will be close to zero and is unlikely to be $1$ or greater, making it highly probable that  $[Y_n]=0.$  (I mistyped the value as "$1$" in my first comment because I had misread your question.)  Thus, it will become highly probable that $n[Y_n]=0$ as $n$ grows large.

Comment: Could you provide me a proof of what you stated? It would be very helpful.

Comment: A proof already appears in your question: letting $k=0$ and applying your formula gives $$\Pr([Y_n]=0)=\Pr(n[Y_n]=0) = \left(\frac{\theta}{\theta}\right)^n - \left(\frac{\theta-1}{\theta}\right)^n =1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{\theta}\right)^n;$$ take the limit as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: Because I am just quoting *your* formula, I urge you to check it for validity: that will expose the problem with it--but the same argument applies.  The fact is that $\theta$ merely establishes a unit of measurement for the $X_i,$ so without any loss of generality you may take $\theta=1.$

Comment: I found the solution to that. If $\theta$ is indeed less than 1 then $P([Y_n]=0)=P(Y_n<1)=1$ trivially.In that case no need to use any formula

Comment: Then, if you solved the problem, you can answer it yourself!

Answer (score 3):

**(a)**   We assume for simplicity that $\theta=1$. Let $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n$ be iid $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and $Y_n$ their minimum. Then
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} 
   \P( Y_n \le y) = 1- \P(Y_n > y) = 1-\P(X_1>y, X_2>y, \dotsc, X_n>y)=\\
   1-\P(X_1 > y)^n = 1- (1-y)^n $$ then
$$ \P(nY_n \le y) = \P(Y_n \le y/n) = 1 - (1-y/n)^n$$
and it is a standard result that this converges to $1-e^{-y}$ when $n$ increases without bounds. That is the cdf of a standard exponential distribution.

**(b)** As the OP found in a comment, $\P(n [Y_n] =0) = \P([Y_n]=0) =
   \P(Y_n < 1) = \P(Y_n \le 1)=1 $